# How to make the axis labels of a Matlab graphic appear bigger in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, matlab

I have included a Matlab.eps in my LaTeX document. But for some reason the axis scaling and also the labels of my axes are really small - I mean the writing is so small, I can barely read it. I don't understand why this is happenning, the graphic looks just fine in Matlab.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[free-standing-units]{siunitx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}
\usepackage{placeins}  

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=140mm]{picture.eps}
\caption{my caption.}
\label{Fig:1}
\end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

the resulting picture looks like this: 
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yj1u9cn6vs45nyn/IMAL_output_spectrum_zoomed.eps?dl=0)

Comment: Can you export it as a PDF file?

Comment: Export the image from Matlab at a smaller size (while keeping the font size) such that you don't have to downscale the image that much when importing it (currently the scaling factor is 0.5 or less). Or export the image as LaTeX code such that the labels are typeset by LaTeX; this has also the advantage that the font for the labels is the same as for the text.

Comment: thx for your comments! So, I don't know how to export the image as LaTeX code. I am new to LaTeX, so if it is too much effort I would prefer a different way. If it is easy however, I will try it! So far I have tried to change the export setup. There is a list of properties that I can change, for example size: But for width and height I can only have "auto". The same for Fonts, it says: Scale font by "auto" %.

Comment: actually, I have just downloaded the matlab2tikz script. When I open my Matlab file, which generates the graphic and then run the matlab2tikz script, this should create a .tikz file, which I should be able to include into my LaTeX document, right? I doesn't work. The Matlab file, which generates my graphic, does many other calculations as well. Can this be the problem?

Comment: one of the errors in LaTeX is: TeX capacity exceeded.